Installing apt package on different partition
I installed debian recently and I got a problem: I have unallocated storage. I wanted to install chromium, but i cant due to low storage. Is there a way to install it on different partition?
Thanks!

that depends on how you've set up your system! Could you edit your question to include the following two things: 1. output of lsblk and 2. output of df -hT. Make sure to use the code formatting button (it is labeled "{ }") in the question editor.
